# No puedo pausar mi programa (C/C++)

Tags: c

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en C por mi cuenta, y estaba haciendo unos cuantos ejemplos de un manual. El problema es el siguiente: Tal como sale en mi libro, le pusieron al programa una pequeña sección de código que pausa lo pausa hasta que el usuario presiona Intro. Pero por alguna razón, cuando intento recoger cualquier tipo de dato, bien con getchar() o scanf(), el programa deja de pausar.

He hecho 2 programas simples para hacer la prueba. El primero al ejecutarlo pausa el programa sin problemas. El segundo termina de ejecutar el programa inmediatamente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num = 4;
    char letra;
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    do
    {
       printf("\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n");
       num = num-1;
    }
    while (num > 0);
    
    /*Esta es la sección que pausa el programa*/
    printf("\nPulse Intro Para finalizar...");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

===================================================================================

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num = 4;
    char letra;
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    do
    {
       printf("\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n");
       num = num-1;
    }
    while (num > 0);

    printf("\nEscribe letra\n");
    scanf("%c", &letra);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    /*Esta es la sección que pausa el programa*/
    printf("\nPulse Intro Para finalizar...");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Estos son los resultados de ejecutar los 2 programas anteriores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como IDE estoy usando Code::Blocks en Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Nunca hagas `fflush(stdin)`. `fflush` está pensado para ser usado, únicamente, con streams de salida ... y `stdin` es un stream de entrada. La documentación lo deja muy claro, el comportamiento es indeterminado y depende del compilador:

- En algunos compiladores funcionará
- En otros casos no hará absolutamente nada
- Otros comportamientos ...

Lo que está sucediendo es que el último `getchar()` está capturando el salto de línea que has introducido para que el programa acepte el caracter

```
scanf("%c", &letra); // <<--- caracter + INTRO
```

puedes descartar ese salto de línea metiendo un getchar() tras el `scanf`

```
scanf("%c", &letra);
getchar();
```

De esta forma, al llegar al último getchar(), el programa se detendrá, esperando una entrada por parte del usuario.

Comment: Gracias!! En mi manual, se usa fflush(stdin) para limpiar el buffer. Esto es lo que dice mi manual: En algunos casos, tras ejecutar una llamada a la funcion scanf o getchar, el buffer del teclado sigue conteniendo información. Esto produce que la próxima vez que se ejecute una de estas funciones, se recoja datos del buffer. Para evitar estos casos, usamos a fflush(stdin) para limpiarlo.

Comment: @dalius https://conclase.net/c/librerias/stdio/fflush

Comment: @dalius Si stream apunta a un stream de salida ...; si no, entonces el comportamiento no está definido

Comment: Luego ya cada compilador te puede indicar su comportamiento en concreto. Así, Microsoft publica lo siguiente: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fflush?view=msvc-170  ... Si la secuencia se ha abierto en **modo de lectura**, o no tiene ningún búfer, **la llamada a fflush no tiene ningún efecto**

Comment: Como un pequeño aporte, en esta otra [publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin) también discuten sobre este tema. Recomiendo que quien lo necesite eche un vistazo si puede, porque es una buena ampliación de la respuesta de @eferion :)